# Can I have multiple network accounts on the same network

Tags: networking

I have a network account through Xfinity hooked up  by ethernet wire thru a Motorola Modem to a HP desk top PC. I want to set up a WiFI account so I can use my wireless iPad.
Your help will be appreciated
Thank you
Jim Kessler

Comment: Most likely both your wired and wireless connection are through the same Xfinity modem. No account information is different in the connections.

Comment: I think your best bet is to call your Xfinity support. this is exactly the kind of thing they can help with, and most importantly, they can tell you whether your Xfinity hardware has built-in wifi (and they can help you connect to it if it's already part of your entitlement). If your hardware doesn't have wifi, I'm sure they'd be willing to rent you a wifi router/AP, and install it for you, for a monthly upcharge, or if you don't want to do that, you could purchase your own wifi router and install it between the motorola device and the PC.